# Canonical form of non-decreasing morphisms

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff

There is a simple lemma that I saw in my algebraic topology class at the University a few years ago (with Vallette): for any non-decreasing morphism $\varphi: [n] \to [m]$ in the category $\Delta$, there exists a unique sequence of indices $i_1 \le \ldots \le i_r$ and $j_1 < \ldots < j_s$ such that
$$\varphi = \delta_{i_1} \ldots \delta_{i_r} \sigma_{j_1} \ldots \sigma_{j_s}$$
You can find this statement as "Proposition 2.15 (Forme normale des morphismes de la catégorie des simplexes)" in the [notes of the class](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Evallette/download/Homotopy%20Theories%202020.pdf).

However, I'd like to cite a more formal reference for my Ph.D. Thesis. Do you know where I can find one?